# Agregar una clase cuando se aplaste el boton ''agregar carrito''

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un proyecto de una tienda LA FAROLA.
Mi problema es que no sé como hacer para que cuando se clikee el boton de carrito este se vuelva rojo(mediante una clase "btn-danger" de bootstrap) y así mostrar que el producto se agregó.
Solo he logrado que cuando se clikee todos se vuelvan rojos pero no sé como hacer para que solo el que se clikee se vuelva rojo.

```js
mostrarProductos(stockProductos)
//AQUI ESTOY CREANDO LAS CARDS DE MIS PRODUCTOS
function mostrarProductos(array) {

    containerProductos.innerHTML="" //reinicia el contenedor, lo vacía pq si no se acumularía

    array.forEach( (producto) => { 
        const div1 = document.createElement("div") //creamos primer div para contener cards
        div1.className = "article__box"
        containerProductos.appendChild(div1)

        const div2 = document.createElement("div") //creamos segundo div para contener la img
        div2.className = "card article__cardbox"
        div2.innerHTML = `<img class='card-img-top'src=${producto.img} alt="" style='width: 20rem;'>`
        div1.appendChild(div2) 
        
        const div3 = document.createElement("div") //creados tercer div para el cardbody
        div3.className= "card-body"
        div3.innerHTML = `
        <p>${producto.marca} </p>
        <p>${producto.modelo}</p>
        <p class='precioProducto'>Precio: ${producto.precio}</p>  
        <button onclick=agregarAlCarrito(${producto.id}) id=${producto.id} class='boton-agregar btn btn-success'>Agregar al carrito</button>
        `   //aprovecho pasarle el evento al producto, es más eficiente.
                
        div2.appendChild(div3)
    });
}


//ACA ESTA MI FUNCION DE AGREGAR AL CARRITO
// AGREGAR AL CARRITO -

const carrito = []
const productosCarrito = document.querySelector(".table tbody")

let btnAgregarCarrito = document.querySelectorAll(".boton-agregar")
console.log(btnAgregarCarrito)
//selecciono donde poner los productos en la tabla

function agregarAlCarrito(itemId) {

    let itemCarrito = carrito.find(el => el.id == itemId)

    if (itemCarrito) {
        itemCarrito.cantidad += 1
    } else {
        let {id, marca, modelo, precio} = stockProductos.find( el=> el.id == itemId)
        carrito.push({id, marca, modelo, precio, cantidad: 1})
    }

    let prodAdd = btnAgregarCarrito.find(el => el.id == Number(itemId))

    if (itemCarrito == 1) {
        prodAdd.className = "btn btn-danger" 
    }


    actualizarCarrito();
}
```

Qué podría hacer? no sé como hacer que el id=${producto.id} puesto en el button "agregar carrito", lo seleccione para así solo el que boton que se clikea se cambie de clase.

link de github: https://jsebast1an.github.io/LaFarola2/

Comment: Deberías probar a usar el event, pasar el evento del click cuando haces click en el boton así puedes acceder a ev.target y por tanto a el elemento exacto que has clickado en vez de buscarlo por ID. Imagina que tienes 400 y clickas en el 23, con ev.target.innerHtml ya sabrías cual es (el 23) y además podrias hacer ev.target.className y tal.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta realizar las validaciones con "===" no con "==". Por ejemplo:

```
let prodAdd = btnAgregarCarrito.find(el => el.id === Number(itemId))
```

Comment: Hola Jonathan, sabes que primero me tira error de que btn.AgregarCarrito.find no es un function xd

Comment: No funciona porque `btnAgregarCarrito` es una lista de nodos iterable, pero no tiene los métodos propios de arreglos. Aunque puedes solucionarlo con `Array.from(btnAgregarCarrito).find(el => el.id === Number(itemId))`

Answer (score 0):

Primero un comentario respecto a esto:

```
    <button onclick=agregarAlCarrito(${producto.id}) id=${producto.id} class='boton-agregar btn btn-success'>Agregar al carrito</button>
    `   //aprovecho pasarle el evento al producto, es más eficiente.
```

Probablemente parezca más fácil hacerlo de esta forma, pero, definitivamente, no es más eficiente, porque lo ideal es usar el evento para tomar el botón que recibió clic.

Considerando eficiencia, puedes escuchar los clics en el contenedor principal (`containerProducts`) y analizar la clase (o etiqueta) del elemento que disparó el evento.

Antes de pasar a eso, te recomiendo usar [atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) para guardar ID del producto, porque los [ID no deben ser numéricos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

```
mostrarProductos(stockProductos)
//AQUI ESTOY CREANDO LAS CARDS DE MIS PRODUCTOS
function mostrarProductos(array) {

    containerProductos.innerHTML="" //reinicia el contenedor, lo vacía pq si no se acumularía

    array.forEach( (producto) => { 
        const div1 = document.createElement("div") //creamos primer div para contener cards
        div1.className = "article__box"
        containerProductos.appendChild(div1)

        const div2 = document.createElement("div") //creamos segundo div para contener la img
        div2.className = "card article__cardbox"
        div2.innerHTML = `<img class='card-img-top'src=${producto.img} alt="" style='width: 20rem;'>`
        div1.appendChild(div2) 
        
        const div3 = document.createElement("div") //creados tercer div para el cardbody
        div3.className= "card-body"
        div3.innerHTML = `
        <p>${producto.marca} </p>
        <p>${producto.modelo}</p>
        <p class='precioProducto'>Precio: ${producto.precio}</p>  
        <button data-id="${producto.id}" class='boton-agregar btn btn-success'>Agregar al carrito</button>
        `;   // No se asigna evento y el ID es por medio de atributo de datos
                
        div2.appendChild(div3)
    });
}


//ACA ESTA MI FUNCION DE AGREGAR AL CARRITO
// AGREGAR AL CARRITO -

const carrito = []
const productosCarrito = document.querySelector(".table tbody")

// No necesitas obtener los botones
// let btnAgregarCarrito = document.querySelectorAll(".boton-agregar")

// Escucha los clics en containerProductos
containerProductos.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // e.target es el elemento que recibió el clic
    // Analiza si el clic fue en un botón, si la clase está incluida
    if(e.target.classList.includes('boton-agregar')) {
        // Ok, el clic fue en un botón, obtener ID de producto desde atributo de datos
        let prodId = e.target.dataset.id;
        // Ejecutar función
        agregarAlCarrito(prodId);
        // Ahora puedes modificar la clase del botón
        e.target.classList.add('btn-danger');
    }
});

// selecciono donde poner los productos en la tabla
function agregarAlCarrito(itemId) {

    let itemCarrito = carrito.find(el => el.id == itemId)

    if (itemCarrito) {
        itemCarrito.cantidad += 1
    } else {
        let {id, marca, modelo, precio} = stockProductos.find( el=> el.id == itemId)
        carrito.push({id, marca, modelo, precio, cantidad: 1})
    }
    // Aquí ya no necesitas obtener el botón
    actualizarCarrito();
}
```