# hacer onclick en un elemento del dom creado tras un evento

Tags: javascript, html, dom

tengo la siguiente funcion que me cambia (borra y crea) unas etiquetas

```
function alpulsarPW(){
var addlabel=document.getElementById('pW');
 addlabel.innerHTML='<input id="pwemail"class=" sinbordefondo" type="password" 
placeholder="Password" size="30"> <label for="pwemail">Password</label> <span id="ojo2" 
class="material-icons ojo2" >visibility</span>';
document.getElementById('pwemail').focus();
ojo2.classList.remove("mostrarojo");
```

}

el div lo tengo así

```
 <div class="row ruser"><!-- pw --> 
          <div id="pW"class="col s12 m6 offset-m3 ese9 input-field ">
            <input id="pwemail"class=" sinbordefondo validate browser-default" type="password" 
placeholder="Password" size="30" onclick="alpulsarPW();"> 
            <span id="ojo" class="material-icons ojo">visibility</span>
            <!-- ojo oculto --> 
            <span id="ojo2" class="material-icons ojo2  mostrarojo" >visibility</span> 
          </div> 
  </div>
```

lo que necesito es que al darle al elemento id=pW, cree el input nuevo junto con el span ojo2, el problema es que si en el html no creo el span id ojo2, me da error el document.getelementbyid

```
var ojo2=document.getElementById("ojo2");



document.getElementById("ojo2").onclick=function(){
    console.log("ojo2");
    var oJo22=document.getElementById('pwemail');
    oJo22.type = '';
    }
```

por lo que mi logica es que al darle al input, cree el input nuevo junto con un span ojo2 nuevo, pero al darle sobre ese ojo2 no hace nada, aparece en el navegador pero no hace nada al pulsar sobre ello (cosa que si hace con el ojo2 original)

Comment: ¿Tienes más de un elemento con `id=ojo2`? `document.getElementById()` solo te va a devolver el primero. Aparte, hay que ver en qué momento asignas el evento, tal vez tengas que delegarlo a otro elemento; puedes ver un ejemplo en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/487469/54039)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a poner el evento de `onClick` dentro de la etiqueta del html de ojo2 como has hecho con el `input` con `id` pwemail de esa manera no fallara al no existir el elemento y cuando hagas click ejecutara la función.

Comment: ya lo intenté pero al pulsar sobre el no hace nada...

Comment: ¿Cuál es la idea de reescribir el contenido del div? Si la idea es hacer un `<span>` visible y otro visible y viceversa prueba en vez de reescribir a jugar con la propiedad `hidden` haciendo visible y invisible el `<span>` de turno. De esa manera también  existirá el elemento en el DOM y podrás vincularle cualquier evento a traveés de JS

Comment: esa es la idea del span, el problema es que tambien tengo que cambiar todo el input, para que tenga otra forma cuando se pulse para escribir, por eso hago el innerHTML, cambiando el input original por otro, pero me borra todo el div, si pudiese cambiar solo el input por otro sería lo suyo así podria mantener el span cambiando el visible...

Comment: El input también lo puedes modificar con JS, deduzco que lo que quieres es cambiar clases, por lo que podrías usar  la propiedad `document.getElementById('elemento').classList.add('clase')` para añadir o `document.getElementById('elemento').classList.remove('clase')` para quitar clases

Comment: Si también quieres añadir o quitar atributos puedes usar `document.getElementById('elemento').setAttribute('size','30')` para añadir o `document.getElementById('elemento').removeAttribute('size')` para quitar atributos. Puedes modificar cualquier etiqueta HTML con JS sin necesidad de remplazarla